# CSS clean animation repeat

Tags: javascript, css

I have an animation using keyframes in CSS

I would like to perform the animation everytime I call a function `animate()` which adds a class with the animation keyframes

So I looked around and found I have to clear the class using `webkitTranstionEnd`, But that would mean I also need to write something for Mozilla, Opera.. Is there a cleaner way to perform a keyframe animation every time I call a function?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend to use a javascript framework like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) (or any other) which is supposed to be cross browser compliant.

Comment: UGhh a jQuery suggestion.. really? Yeah.. totally just include 2k lines of code to clear css animations!

Comment: Well the webkit's css are very nice but unfortunately some of them are still proprietary (no opera, i.e. equivalent). Now what is best ? to do something in jQuery which will be the same anywhere or to deal with several css styles which may differs from one browser to another ?

Comment: I've considered this but JQuery's constant recalculation during redraw makes the animation lag on many computers

Comment: Mmm ok, otherwise some people are using http://prefixr.com/ it is supposed to do the job you are asking for, but I personally prefer having the hand on the items via javascript.